# R List with sub-lists: Extract all elements that match a rule into array

Tags: r

I have a R list of objects which are again lists of various types. I want "cost" value for all objects whose category is "internal". What's a good way of achieving this?

If I had a data frame I'd have done something like

```
my_dataframe$cost[my_dataframe$category == "internal"]
```

What's the analogous idiom for a list?

```
mylist<-list(list(category="internal",cost=2),
list(category="bar",cost=3),list(category="internal",cost=4),
list(category='foo',age=56))
```

Here I'd want to get c(2,4). Subsetting like this does not work:

```
mylist[mylist$category == "internal"]
```

I can do part of this by:

```
temp<-sapply(mylist,FUN = function(x) x$category=="internal")
mylist[temp]
[[1]]
[[1]]$category
[1] "internal"

[[1]]$cost
[1] 2


[[2]]
[[2]]$category
[1] "internal"

[[2]]$cost
[1] 4
```

But how do I get just the costs so that I can (say) sum them up etc.? I tried this but does not help much:

```
unlist(mylist[temp])
  category       cost   category       cost 
"internal"        "2" "internal"        "4"
```

Is there a neat, compact idiom for doing what I want?

Answer (score 6):

The idiom you are looking for is

```
sapply(mylist, "[[", "cost")
```

which returns a list of the extracted vector, should it exist, and NULL if it does not.

```
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4

[[4]]
NULL
```

If you just want the sum of categories that are internal you can do the following assuming you want a vector.

```
sum(sapply(mylist[temp], "[[", "cost"))
```

And if you want a list of the same result you can do

```
sapply(mylist,function(x) x[x$category == "internal"]$cost)
```

One of the beautiful, but challenging things about R is that there are so many ways to express the same language.

You might note from the other answers that you can interchange `sapply` and `lapply` since lists are just heterogenous vectors, the following will also return `6`.

```
do.call("sum",lapply(mylist, function(x) x[x[["category"]] == "internal"]$cost))
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Can you explain more how the [[ works? Is that an operator?

Comment: It is one of the 3 extraction operators in R. There are benefits to using each, in general, `[` and `[[` have a similar function on vectors, but work differently on recursive vectors, e.g., lists. Note in addition to the last line of code above, that `do.call("sum",lapply(mylist, function(x) x[x[["category"]] == "internal"]["cost"]))` doesn't work, but `do.call("sum",lapply(mylist, function(x) x[x[["category"]] == "internal"][["cost"]))` does work.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another attempt, this time using `?Filter` and a custom function to do the necessary selecting:

```
sum(sapply(Filter(function(x) x$category=="internal", mylist), `[[`, "cost"))
#[1] 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Could try something like this. For all sublists, if the category is "internal", get the cost, otherwise return NULL which will be ignored when you `unlist` the result:

```
sum(unlist(lapply(mylist, function(x) if(x$category == "internal") x$cost)))
# [1] 6
```

A safer way is to also check if `category` exists in the sublist by checking the length of `category`:

```
sum(unlist(lapply(mylist, function(x) if(length(x$category) && x$category == "internal") x$cost)))
# [1] 6
```

This will avoid raising an error if the sublist doesn't contain the `category` field.

Comment: Maybe just use `lapply` since you are using `unlist` anyway?

Comment: @Sumedh Yes. Not sure why the simplify not working when there is NULL in the list.

Comment: @Psidom - length(0) objects like NULL can't be coerced to a vector along with length(1) objects.

Answer (score 1):

The `purrr` package has some nice utilities for manipulating lists. Here, `keep` lets you specify a predicate function that returns a Boolean for whether to keep a list element:

```
library(purrr)

mylist %>% 
    keep(~.x[['category']] == 'internal') %>% 
    # now select the `cost` element of each, and simplify to numeric
    map_dbl('cost') %>% 
    sum()
## [1] 6
```

The predicate structure with `~` and `.x` is a shorthand equivalent to

```
function(x){x[['category']] == 'internal'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I approached your question by `rlist` package. This method is similar to a`purrr` package method @alistaire mentioned.

```
library(rlist); library(dplyr)

mylist %>% 
  list.filter(category=="internal") %>% 
  list.mapv(cost) %>% sum()
    # list.mapv returns each member of a list by an expression to a vector.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` option:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(mylist) %>% 
  filter(category == 'internal') %>% 
  summarize(total = sum(cost))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
    total
    <dbl>
  1     6
```